# JCL logging in Glassfish via SLF4j

Tags: java, logging, glassfish-3, slf4j, apache-commons-logging

I'm trying to setup logging of application on Glassfish server. I use SLF4j to aggregate everything and Logback binding to write the files. Also I added `log4j-over-slf4j`, `jul-to-slf4j` and `jcl-over-slf4j` libraries to the project. Of course `slf4j-api` and Logback ones are there too. All the libraries are in project `WEB-INF/lib` and in `glassfish/lib/endorsed`.

So the idea is: redirect everything to SLF4j and then log with Logback.

In the code I have the following piece for test:

```
jclLog.debug("Login JCL: Debug level");
jclLog.error("Login JCL: Error level");
log4jLog.debug("Login Log4j: Debug level");
log4jLog.error("Login Log4j: Error level");
slfLog.debug("Login SLF4j: Debug level");
slfLog.error("Login SLF4j: Error level");
```

After execution there are log entries og Log4j and SLF4j in Logback-configured log files. But JCL entries are not there. They get to server.log file instead.

The question is: why JCL entries are catched with Glassfish logger and how could it be prevented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't (yet) do this. See http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-6666 for the relevant bug report.